# How to extract numbers from character in R

Tags: r, extract

I have a column with values C(1), C(2), ...C(30), C(31) and I need to extract only numbers.

```
x<-as.character(c("C(1)", "C(2)", "C(3)"))

a<-as.numeric(substr(x,3,3))
```

substr() did not help because for 2-digit numbers I need to substr 3 and 4 value.

Comment: Hi try this hope this will help.  ```x1 <- ifelse(nchar(x==1),substr(x,3,3),substr(x,3,4))```

Comment: From the stringr package: `stringr::str_extract(x, "[0-9]+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to remove all non numerical characters. This can be done using different functions. I like to use the `stringr` package to deal with characters:

```
library(stringr)

x <- as.character(c("C(1)", "C(2)", "C(3)"))

# Replace all non numerical characters to a empty space
y <- str_replace_all(x, "[^0-9]", "" )

a <- as.numeric(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and fastest way to do this is to use a regex to match digits:

```
x <- as.character(c("C(1)", "C(2)", "C(30)"))
vec <- as.numeric(regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+", x)))
vec
# Output:
1 2 30
```

Comment: Try it with this string: c("C(1)", "C(20)", "C(3)")

Comment: Thanks for pulling me up on this one. I amended the code above.

Comment: thanks you, guys, all approaches worked!